# Проблема с установкой модулей в python

Tags: python, cmd, ide

При попытке установить любой модуль (допустим pyinstaller) через команду pip install выдает следующую ошибку:

> WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
>   Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
>   To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.

Пытался решить проблему так: python -m pip install имя_модуля. Но также выдавало ошибку:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_82jqqc'

Вся проблема началась пару дней назад, когда я изучал python, читая книгу *"a byte of python"*. Там нужно было установить gnuwin32.

Ну, собственно, я и установил. Программа, которую мы писали заработала, но когда я хотел конвертировать ее в exe полилась куча ошибок.

Я пытался менять PATH, но ситуация только ухудшилась.
Кроме вышесказанных ошибок была еще огромная куча, но их я уже не помню.

Причем раньше все было хорошо. Без проблем устанавливал библиотеки.

Comment: Попробуй снести питон и поставить новый. Еще может быть компилятор дурит голову с путями

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогает

Comment: WARNING - это не ошибка, это предупреждение. И попробуйте от администратора запускать команды, если Permission denied.

Comment: Не помогло, выводит тоже самое

Comment: Попробуйте обновить pip, хотя я и сомневаюсь, что это поможет. Это делается через python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Это я тоже пытался делать, не помогало